# Ошибка при вставке данных из Python в MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x, pandas

У меня есть код:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
data=[[18:04:23, 24, 0.63790, 45, 892]
[18:12:27, 32, 0.54881, 36, 701]
[18:34:34, 46, 0.45972, 27, 610]
[18:59:56, 02, 0.36363, 08, 529]
[18:59:56, 02, 0.36363, 08, 529]
[18:59:56, 02, 0.36363, 08, 529]
[18:59:56, 02, 0.36363, 08, 529]
[19:06:23, 67, 0.27054, 99, 438]
[19:23:43, 56, 0.18145, 80, 347]
[19:32:45, 99, 0.09236, 71, 256]
[19:43:12, 13, 0.90327, 62, 165]
[19:43:12, 13, 0.90327, 62, 165]
[20:04:00, 24, 0.81418, 53, 074]
[20:38:24, 54, 0.72509, 44, 983]
[20:47:46, 75, 0.63690, 35, 892]
[21:04:59, 83, 0.54781, 26, 701]
[06:04:23, 67, 0.52342, 26, 345]]
db_connection = 'mysql+pymysql://AAA:OOO@localhost/PPAP'   
conn = create_engine(db_connection)
for i in data:
    pd.read_sql('INSERT IGNORE test (Time,ID,X,Y) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s)' % (i[0],i[1],i[2],i[3]), conn)
```

Код должен просто вставлять в бд данные, однако возникает следующая ошибка:
ResourceClosedError: This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically.

По какой-то мне неведомой причине это происходит именно в питоне. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pd.read_sql` предназначен для того, чтобы читать данные из базы. Чтобы складывать данные в базу, используйте `pandas.DataFrame.to_sql`.

При этом обратите внимание на то, как он работает: [ссылка на документацию](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)

Этот метод вызывается у датафрейма, и он просто выгружает все данные в соответствующие колонки одной таблицы. Соответственно, нужно будет ваши данные сначала уложить в датафрейм.

Но, на самом деле, вообще не понятно, зачем вам здесь пандас. Вы можете просто использовать `conn.execute`, чтобы выполнить ваш запрос.

UPD: По вашему вопросу в комментариях - попробуйте вот так:

```
db_connection = 'mysql+pymysql://AAA:OOO@localhost/PPAP'   
engine = create_engine(db_connection)
conn = engine.connect()
# И дальше уже делаете ваши запросы через conn.execute
```

Comment: Поменял на conn.execute, но теперь выдает ошибку: AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'translate'

Comment: @Denzel, я дописал в ответ, попробуйте

Comment: Забыл conn удалить в конце запроса. Он как раз и выдавал эту ошибку. Спасибо! Ps: Данных очень много. Есть ли какой-то другой более быстрый способ вставлять данные в бд?

Comment: @Denzel, лучше задать это отдельным вопросом. Так больше вероятность, что в будущем люди с похожей проблемой смогут найти ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше воспользоваться Pandas - код будет гораздо проще и понятнее и, скорее всего, работать будет быстрее по сравнению с рукописными циклами:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Time','ID','X','Y','Z'])
df.to_sql('table_name', conn, if_exists='replace')
```

**NOTE:** В зависимости от ваших целей вам возможно придется указать другое значение для параметра `if_exists`:

> **if_exists** : {`fail`, `replace`, `append`}, default `fail`
>
> How to behave if the table already exists.
>
> **fail**: Raise a ValueError.
>
> **replace**: Drop the table before inserting new values.
>
> **append**: Insert new values to the existing table.